# Cannot find project.android-studio in cocos2dx

Tags: android, android-studio

I download Cocos2d-x **3.17.2** "last vesion" and i installed to Use it with android Studio ..

But when i run it i can't find the specific folder for android Studio "**project.android-studio**" it give me just ""**project.android**"..

please share any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The `proj.android` folder is the correct one to use with Android Studio.

After you load Android Studio, select `Open an existing Android Studio project`, then locate the `proj.android`, select it, and click `OK`, as you can see in the following image:

[image: Open File or Project dialog]